# how to remove the repeated words in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

My PHP script is like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rc)) {

    echo $post;
    $pieces = explode("|", $row['texto']);
    $row['texto'] = $pieces[0];
    $result = strtolower(str_replace('"', '&quot;', $row['texto'])).'"'.$row['id'];
    $a[] = $result;
    //$a[]= array('texto'=>$result);
    $post = "\n";
}
$b = array_unique($a);
foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
          echo $value;

    }
```

What I am trying to do is to remove the redundant value from the array using `array_unique()` and print it. Every thing is working fine other than the fact that in my array I could only see one value that's the first value I guess.

Can some one help me out? What is wrong with this code?

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to eliminate __consecutive__ duplicate words like `the` in a phrase like `I see the the sun in the sky`, but not in `the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

Comment: @MarkBaker yes the array has duplicate value I am trying to  remove it

Comment: Could you use `print_r($a)` to give us a sample of what your `$a` array's contents are like?

Comment: @AndreaFaulds sure I can .

Comment: What do you want to o in the case of `I had had a latte in starbucks, but my friend had only had an glass of milk`

Comment: @Vikram: Please write a sample input and corresponding output.

Comment: @Vikram A little pice of un-related advice; You should use PDO or at least mysqli to communicate with your database instead of mysql; It's much more secure and optimized that way..
[PDO Tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
PS: Good to see another developer drumming ;)

Comment: `= >` is this a typo?

Comment: Is that your actual code, by the way? Following on from what @bansi said, `= >` wouldn't be valid, only `=>`. If this script actually executes, then why is their a syntax error in your question?

Comment: @bansi it was a typo sorry I fixed it .

Comment: @AndreaFaulds I added an Image file of the result output

Comment: @Vikram Could you try using `print_r($b);` or `var_dump($b);` ?

Comment: @AndreaFaulds thats what I did in the server script then I am getting the output using an ajax call actually . Its the same thing

Comment: @Vikram So is what's in the screenshot above var_dump($b); or var_dump($a); ?

Comment: you are appending `$row['id']` to the value, are you really including that also?

Comment: @bansi I guess that is the problem yeah I think I shoud remove that let me try that . I am not really using it btw

Comment: @Vikram Again, is that your actual code? The output doesn't match the code, so please paste your *actual* code.

Comment: @bansi after I removed the row['id] . The function is working fine

Answer (score -2):

```
$row['texto'] = $pieces[0];
```

this will take only the first value of the exploded array.

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rc)) {

        echo $post;
        $pieces = explode("|", $row['texto']);
        $row['texto'] = $pieces;

        $post = "\n";
    }
    $b = array_unique($row['texto']);
    foreach($b as $value) {
 $result = strtolower(str_replace('"', '&quot;', $value));
        echo $value;

    }
```

Please try this.

Comment: no :). inside the while loop I am exploding it to get the first word of the string that has `|` as seperator and after that I am creating another array . `$b` from that I have to take out unique words . Please have a look on the image

Comment: I believe they were deliberately taking the first piece of each row. This isn't their problem.

Comment: @AndreaFaulds yes thats not the problem

Comment: you create $b like this `'$b = array_unique($row['texto']);'`

But here '$row['texto'] = $pieces[0];' you change $row['texto'] to a single value

Comment: @arunc this answer is wrong in at least two way: do not work (overwrite `$row['texto']` at each row from mysql result so only one at end) and do not answer the OP question.